# Laravel Error 500 on adding new column in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache, laravel-collection

I have a table with these columns in a Mysql database;

```
tlid
uid
did
mail
mailed
maileddate
phone
driveup
taxdeed
taxcertificateoneyear
taxcertificatetwoyears
delinquenttaxes
preforeclosure
realestateowned
qualified
trackdate
created_at
updated_at
```

Whenever I try to add another column, a query that uses a left join to pull data form this table causes a 500 Internal server error.

When I remove the table added the site would start working again. The column I added was not a reserved keyword, tried several different words but same error.The site is hosted on Godaddy

This is the query;
`$pageData['allleads'] = DB::table('deals')->where('deals.category', 'lead')->where('deals.uid', '2')->where('deals.active', '1')->where('deals.locked', '0')->leftJoin('track_leads', 'track_leads.did', '=', 'deals.id')->leftJoin('lead_progressions', 'lead_progressions.did', '=', 'deals.id')->groupBy('id')->get();`

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: And what is the query?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, also check in `storage/logs`

Comment: The error from the log is [2022-04-30 01:05:29] local.ERROR: Target class [LeadController] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [LeadController] does not exist. at /home/kiinc/public_html/dealcollab/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877). But the same class is there when I remove the column and it works then.

Comment: That's a log line from April.

Comment: Sorry, this is the last error: [2022-06-30 10:39:37] local.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected identifier "taxcertificatetwoyears" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected identifier \"taxcertificatetwoyears\" at /home/kiinc/public_html/dealcollab/app/Http/Controllers/LeadController.php:96). But I  have since fixed that issue where the string "taxcertificatetwoyears" was somehow pasted in a line of code but I removed it. Someone asked for the query, I will post it soon, but it is the same query that works when I remove the column that was added.

Comment: The query is now added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

in your case i will recommend you to do a next thing:

1. Instead of composing query on eloquent level - firstly do that on sql level. To actually debug the problem you can follow next approach:

```php
DB::table('deals')->where('deals.category', 'lead')->where('deals.uid', '2')->where('deals.active', '1')->where('deals.locked', '0')->leftJoin('track_leads', 'track_leads.did', '=', 'deals.id')->leftJoin('lead_progressions', 'lead_progressions.did', '=', 'deals.id')->groupBy('id')->dd();
```

The output will be formatted to SQL, and you can copy/paste it to actual SQL server and execute the query there, there is a big chance, that the problem in SQL syntax.

Comment: I tried this and the query executed with no errors, only a warning. and I got the 18,719 results as expected. select * from `deals` left join `track_leads` on `track_leads`.`did` = `deals`.`id` left join `lead_progressions` on `lead_progressions`.`did` = `deals`.`id` where `deals`.`category` = ? and `deals`.`uid` = ? and `deals`.`active` = ? and `deals`.`locked` = ? group by `id`. Ofcource I substituted the ? for the actual values. The warning was "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."

Comment: For this error I will also add the it is not making an entry into the logs, the previous log posted was from another error.(I deleted all the logs and nothing new is added there when I get this 500 error.

Comment: Try to groupBy('table_name.id').

Comment: I tried this also, that did not make any difference. Only time it works again is when I delete the column I added in Mysql. If I change the name of a column it also stops working, when I put it back to the name it had it starts working again. Makes me think that my install of Mysql has become corrupted. I even deleted the database and restored from a backup I had.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the error message from laravel  :) since now i do have only assumptions. Thanks

Comment: It did not get to a point where it logged an error from Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue. It turns out an error was logged from PHP in the public folder which is the root.

[06-Jun-2022 00:12:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 19212392 bytes) in /home/home-site/public_html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line 63

So I increased the memory_limit from 128Mb to 512Mb in a .user.ini file.(I take it this could have been adjusted in php.ini also)

I was loading 18,738 records to a datatable so my next move is to implement Ajax to lazy load a smaller amount of records.